# Letter ő. Which PHP encoding/decoding works the best?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I'm from Hungary, and our language use the letter "ő". If I upload anything to my mysql database through php, to a latin1_swedish_ci encoded column, it ends up being weird, but after all when I fetch some datas from the database I can easily use a utf8_decode($string) to be compatable with my utf-8 meta charset.

At the contacts part of my page, there's a simple e-mail form, which sends the strings via a form to an e-mail address. Problem is, I've tried different encodings, and the best was utf8_decode($string) but it still prints out the letter "ő"(s) as question marks when I get the mail.

> For example:   Törtető emberiség védelmezője   becomes   Törtet?
>   emberiség védelmez?je

Any ideas for a better encoding/decoding ?

Comment: hard to say without knowing, if you set encoding of your webside correctly. all the parts in your workflow (websides meta-tag, php-file-encoding, database) have to be set to utf, then you have no problem.

Comment: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely UTF-8. We are using it all the time for our Estonian letters like öäüõ.

You probably have to set your header as well.

Like this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

BR's

Comment: I was already answering my own question, but you were faster :)  
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. If any of my fellow hungarians or other nation's people who use a weird language would like to solve their letter problems via php use this method.

```
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Paste it to the start of your code, so the encoding will be fine :)